# ImageJ won't start in Python. CalledProcessError java version

Tags: java, python-3.x, image, imagej

I have the following code, which worked perfectly a couple days ago

```
import imagej

ij = imagej.init()
```

However, after starting my computer today I'm getting the following error

```
CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\\path\\to\\java\\bin\\java.exe', '-version']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

The stack trace is the following.

```
CalledProcessError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [11], in <cell line: 3>()
      1 import imagej
----> 3 ij = imagej.init()

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\imagej\__init__.py:1496, in init(ij_dir_or_version_or_endpoint, mode, add_legacy, headless)
   1493     raise EnvironmentError("Sorry, the interactive mode is not available on macOS.")
   1495 if not sj.jvm_started():
-> 1496     success = _create_jvm(ij_dir_or_version_or_endpoint, mode, add_legacy)
   1497     if not success:
   1498         raise RuntimeError("Failed to create a JVM with the requested environment.")

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\imagej\__init__.py:1603, in _create_jvm(ij_dir_or_version_or_endpoint, mode, add_legacy)
   1601     sj.config.add_option("-Djava.awt.headless=true")
   1602 try:
-> 1603     if hasattr(sj, "jvm_version") and sj.jvm_version()[0] >= 9:
   1604         # Disable illegal reflection access warnings.
   1605         sj.config.add_option("--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED")
   1606         sj.config.add_option("--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED")

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scyjava\_java.py:140, in jvm_version()
    137 if java is None:
    138     raise RuntimeError(f"No java executable found inside: {p}")
--> 140 version = subprocess.check_output(
    141     [str(java), "-version"], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT
    142 ).decode()
    143 m = re.match('.*version "(([0-9]+\\.)+[0-9]+)', version)
    144 if not m:

File ~\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py:424, in check_output(timeout, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    421         empty = b''
    422     kwargs['input'] = empty
--> 424 return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
    425            **kwargs).stdout

File ~\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py:528, in run(input, capture_output, timeout, check, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    526     retcode = process.poll()
    527     if check and retcode:
--> 528         raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
    529                                  output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
    530 return CompletedProcess(process.args, retcode, stdout, stderr)

CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\\Users\\andre\\anaconda3\\Library\\bin\\bin\\java.exe', '-version']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

I have no idea how to solve it, maybe it's a problem with my JVM configuration?